# How to add a logo in the top left of the page?

Tags: graphics, lyx, titles, logos

I am using lyx and I need to add the university logo in the top left of the title page, but I couldn't I am using book document.. is there a code or package can help me? I am a new user not expert

Comment: Just one or every page? If one, just the title page? What `\documentclass` do you have? In the header, or just "top left... somewhere"?

Comment: ...I'm hinting towards requesting something like a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764). I understand you're using LyX, but we'll need more details to successfully address your question.

Comment: I agree with Werner. Remember that a .lyx file is just a text file so you can copy/paste it here. For more information see https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: I just leave my standard link for this occasion: [How to customize my titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/209993)